# Named template resource-uri is not available (XSLT language)

Tags: xslt

I am getting `Named template resource-uri is not available` in my XSLT project

the code is as per below,

```
<xsl:variable name="resource-uri">
    <xsl:call-template name="resource-uri">
        <xsl:with-param name="uri" select="$link-uri/html:link/@rdf:resource"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="var" select="$link-uri/html:link"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Getting the same error in another code `Named template normalize-language is not available`

the code is as per below,

```
<xsl:variable name="html"><div>
        <xsl:call-template name="normalize-language">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$validHTML"/>
        </xsl:call-template></div>
</xsl:variable>
```

How can I resolve this error I am very beginner in XSLT language.Can anyone help me regarding this help I am very thankful to you!

Comment: There should be templates with name `resource-uri` and `normailize-language` viz. `<xsl:template name="resource-uri">` and `<xsl:template name="normalize-language">` in your code. Since these templates are not present, the errors are thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your stylesheet contains an instruction `xsl:call-template name="X"` then it must also contain a template declared with `xsl:template name="X"`. The error message indicates that there is no such template in your stylesheet.

(I'm wondering if you have just copied this code from an example somewhere without actually understanding what it does? Can I suggest that's not a very efficient way to learn a new language? The trouble is, until you have read some introductory material introducing the concepts of the language, you have no chance of understanding the error messages when you get things wrong, because the error messages will use unfamiliar terminology.)